# Tabs don't change to “active” - jQuery and rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have this nav menu with 2 tabs:

```
<div id="user_menu">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><%= link_to "Group1", group1_friends_path(@user), :remote => true %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Group2", group2_friends_path(@user), :remote => true %></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I've managed to let Ajax render certain partials. Now, when I click on the tabs the partials load in my target placeholder div. I buid this jquery script to handle this,

**tab.js:** which I placed in assest/javascripts/

```
$('#user_menu a').click(function (e) {
    $('ul.nav-tabs li.active').removeClass('active')
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active')
})
```

**My application.js looks like this:**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: does the chrome firebug console display any error? Do all your links have parent list items?

Comment: @JohnMerlino I dont get any error in firebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Maybe it's beeing executed before the document is ready?

```
$(function() {
  $('#user_menu a').click(function (e) {
    $('ul.nav-tabs li.active').removeClass('active')
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active')
  });
});
```